# How to view xcode logs in eas-build --local

Tags: expo, eas

My build works on EAS but fails locally. Command:

```
eas build --platform ios --local --profile development
```

The archive step fails:

```
Build failed
Fastlane build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run fastlane" and "Xcode Logs" phases for more information.
Fastlane errors in most cases are not printed at the end of the output, so you may not find any useful information in the last lines of output when looking for an error message.
```

How do I view the Xcode logs? These are available to download for EAS hosted builds.

Comment: I have the same issue I don't know if you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434035/expo-sdk-46-ios-build-failed-in-fastlane-step

Answer (score 0):

#### use env var

it turns out the logs are ephemeral unless you explicitly keep them - [github issue comment](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1643#issuecomment-1398536223)

to keep the logs set the environment variable `EAS_LOCAL_BUILD_SKIP_CLEANUP`

#### example

```bash
EAS_LOCAL_BUILD_SKIP_CLEANUP=1 eas build --output dist/ios.ipa --profile preview --platform ios --non-interactive --local --wait
```

#### output

- persisted logs warning in yellow

  [image: cli output]
- clicking that path opened this

  [image: logs and temp files]